# How can I get values to print out with a page break using php?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form element that I am running through a PHP page that is rendered onto another page that the user can print. The values appear in the form on after the other into a  one on top of the other with page breaks. This is the javascript...

```
var endwallPanelLengths = [totalHeightInches];
var i = 0;
document.getElementById("test83").value = "";
while (endwallPanelLengths[i] > eaveInches) 
{
    endwallPanelLengths.push(endwallPanelLengths[i] - peakHeightDecrease);
    document.getElementById("test83").value += endwallPanelLengths[i] + "&quot;," + "\n";
    i++;
}
```

"test83" is the id and name of the textarea in which the values show up. now when I submit the form to be handled by PHP the values are not printing with page breaks but in a line like this > 123",124",125" etc and I need them to be one over the other with breaks. This is the PHP code.

```
if (!empty($endwallPanels)) {
    $table .= '<tr>
    <td> 4 </td>
    <td>' .$endwallPanels. '</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>' .$sideColor. '</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

$endwallPanels is the variable that contains the values from the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, but if I do, when you put them into the textarea they are shown one per line, but on printing them with PHP, they're all on the same line?

If this is the case, it's because textareas use newline characters `\n` to create a line break. Browsers will interpret this as any other whitespace, so will print it just as a space. You can fix this in your php but using [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), e.g. `nl2br($endwallPanels)`, which converts newline characters to HTML `<br>` characters.

Comment: I just created a new variable called $endwallPanelBreaks=nl2br(endwallPanels) and it worked, thank you.